# need to use jquery in node

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

I have a node,mongodb setup on windows and in process of developing a webapp. In the server.js file i have a post route like this:

```
var http=require('http');
app.post("/leadAPI/ed",function(request,response){

var data={firstname:request.body.firstname,lastname:request.body.lastname,email:request.body.email,areaOfInterest:request.body.areaOfInterest,highestEducation:request.body.highestEducation,daytimePhone:request.body.daytimePhone,eveningPhone:request.body.eveningPhone,addressOne:request.body.addressOne,addressTwo:request.body.addressTwo,city:request.body.city,state:request.body.state,zip:request.body.zip,country:request.body.country};

edDoc=new edModel(data);
edDoc.save();

var options={
hostname:'www.someRemoteUrl.com',
port:80,
path:'/some/path/on/that/url?'+$.param(data),
method:'POST'
};

var req=http.request(options,function(res){
console.log(res);
});


});
```

This doesn't work because $(param) won't run in node without npming the jquery. problem is that installation of jquery package for node on windows doesn't get installed properly. Is there any other way around? I need to build a query string out of that object in a clean way.

Comment: Including the whole of jQuery is a bit overkill if all you need from it is building the query string.

Comment: so what do you suggest?

Comment: @beNerd You should be able to use [`require('querystring')`](http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html), esp. [`qs.stringify()`](http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_stringify_obj_sep_eq).

Comment: Do you even know where jQuery is for? You want to for example fade, animate or change css server side?

Comment: @Bondye Yes i know what jquery does very well :). Don't be so rude. I just didn't know the querystring package available with npm and so the question.

Comment: @Bondye Just FYI, jQuery can be used on the server side, and there is an NPM available. Changing display properties of DOM elements is only a small part of what jQuery does, and a lot of people find use of jQuery for node.js.

Comment: @Munim Than they use jQuery wrong... They mostly don't understand JavaScript so they use jQuery because selecting/querying is easier..

Answer (score 1):

There are much easier ways to construct a querystring. You really shouldn't install jQuery for it if that is all you want to do, even if you could. Try the querystring npm package.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use jquery in node, then take look at [cheerio](https://npmjs.org/package/cheerio). It is a tiny, fast, and elegant implementation of core jQuery designed specifically for the server.